# Minor and Major Tick Mark Label format on Ms Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspchart

This is my first attempt at trying to use .net Chart Control and I am trying to achieve some specific Axis label format pattern.

I have a two Line series that have common X-Primary axis and it is of `DateTime` data type.

I am tyring to

1. Show days of Month on Minor Tick and Month of year on Major Tick mark labels.
2. Problem is I am unable to use 
   `mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format;`
   to get desired Minor Tick mark label formatting as it applies to  both Major and minor Grids/Ticks. Basically, what I am trying to know is how to apply different label format for each major and Minor Grid lines/ Tick labels on Axis. 
   some snippets of my code  - not exclusive

   ```
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{MMM}";
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = true;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = true;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 1;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 1;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
   mychart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorTickMark.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
   ```

Any suggestion how to go about accomplishing this is much appreciated.